# Can we have a converse Skolem paradox?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, first-order-logic, model-theory

My information about models is not that great, so the question here is elementary in that field.

> Can we have a model of ZF or ZF-regularity, in which there are two sets $x,y$ and such that no bijection exists between them, i.e. externally speaking, but at the same time we have the statement of existence of a bijection between them is satisfied in it?

I'm asking that because what is seen from outside of a model can conflict with what's satisfied in it! So for example a countable model of ZF does have a bijection between *every* set in it and the set $\omega$ of all finite von Neumann ordinals, and $\omega$ is a set in it also, but still the model does fulfill Cantor's theorem, and so it satisfy the statement that MOST sets are uncountable! While in fact (externally speaking) *All* of them are countable! This is the Skolem paradox. The explanation given is that the bijection is seen externally and it exists, but it is not in the model, i.e. its a subset of the model but not an element of the model. I'm asking if the converse can also happen? That's why I call it converse Skolem paradox.

My own personal guess is that NO such a paradox can exist. But I'm not sure of the satisfaction conditions in Models, and my knowledge about those is indeed trivial. That's why I asked this rather trivial question.

Comment: Just to clarify: Suppose $M$ is an arbitrary model of ZF, and $x$ and $y$ are elements of $M$. When you talk about "a bijection between $x$ and $y$", do you mean a bijection between $\{z\in M\mid M\models z\in x\}$ and $\{z\in M\mid M\models z\in y\}$?

Comment: @AlexKruckman, Yes!

Comment: By the way, I did not cast the downvote or the close vote. It's a very reasonable question!

Comment: @AlexKruckman Indeed, and the answer to this question in fact can be fruitfully traced back to a basic rule in our semantics. I suspect the negative response is from someone unfamiliar with the topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this cannot happen. And in fact this has nothing to do with $\mathsf{ZF}$: more broadly, if $M$ is any structure and $A,B$ are definable-with-parameters subsets of $M$, then if $M\models$ "There is a bijection between $A$ and $B$" we in fact have a bijection between $A$ and $B$.

*(Note that this addresses the "translation" issue Alex Kruckman mentions in his comment above: if $M$ is an $\{\in\}$-structure, each $x\in M$ corresponds to the definable-in-$x$ set $\{y\in M: M\models y\in x\}$. Also note that when talking about $\{\in\}$-structures, the word "set" is dangerously overloaded since it can refer to elements of $M$ or to subsets of $M$ in the external sense. It's the latter meaning which is used here when I talk about "definable sets.")*

The precise statement is:

> Suppose $M$ is a structure, $A,B$ are definable-with-parameters subsets of $M$, and $\varphi$ is a formula with parameters in $M$ such that $$M\models\forall x\in A\exists!y\in B(\varphi(x,y))$$ and $$M\models\forall x_1,x_2\in A, y\in B(\varphi(x_1,y)\wedge\varphi(x_2,y)\rightarrow x_1=x_2).$$ Then in reality there is a bijection from $A$ to $B$.

And the proof is quite quick:

> Consider the map sending $a\in A$ to the unique $b\in B$ such that $M\models \varphi(a, b)$.

This may seem slippery - what *exactly* are we using to conclude this? Well, we're using the fact that "$=$" is always interpreted as actual equality in a structure. If we allow structures which are allowed to interpret the $=$-symbol as an arbitrary equivalence relation (so: first-order logic without built-in equality), then this argument breaks down and indeed structures can think bijections exist when in fact they do not. E.g. such a structure can think that there is a bijection between a truly-two-element-set and a truly-one-element-set by virtue of thinking that the two elements of the truly-two-element-set are equal when they are in fact not.

Comment: As written, this depends being able to express "There is a bijection between $A$ and $B$" in first-order logic. That's no problem in set theory, where we can quantify over functions, but it doesn't work in general structures. I think the more general explanation is that if $A$ and $B$ are definable (with parameters) sets and $f\colon A\to B$ is a definable (with parameters) function, and if $M\models $"$f$ is a bijection ", then $\widehat{f}$ is actually a bijection.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Yes, I was being sloppy. I'll edit for clarity.

Comment: @AlexKruckman I've edited to clarify. Let me know if this doesn't address your concern.